# What is the best way to move a folder inside itself?

Tags: c#, winapi, directory

Assuming I want to move a folder inside itself, with its former contents empty but for the new folder, how would I best go about it using code. Normally, in explorer, you would do this by cutting the content of the folder and placing it in a new folder created inside the original folder.

***i.e.***

> Original Path: C:\Users\Previous
>
> New Path: C:\Users\Previous\Previous

Comment: I'd normally create a new folder with a different name, move the old folder inside it, and then rename the new folder back to the old name. That should be one create, one move operation, and one rename. Your Cut/Paste method would require one move for each file/folder contained within.

Comment: 1. Rename to `C:\Users\Previous_Some_Temp_Name`. 2. Create `C:\Users\Previous`. 3. Use `Directory.Move` to move `C:\Users\Previous_Some_Temp_Name` into `C:\Users\Previous`.  OK, I now see Damien's approach which is equivalent, but somehow feels cleaner to me.

Answer (score 0):

1. cerate the temp folder : c:\user\temp
2. move the directory with [Move](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.moveto.aspx) from c:\user\previous to : c:\user\temp
3. rename the temp folder with [Move](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.moveto.aspx) from c:\user\temp to c:\user\previous

Comment: You cannot do that with a single call to `Move`

Answer (score 0):

As you wanted to move folder and its contents to a sub folder with the same name, you could do as follows:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CopyContentsToSubFolderWithSameName(@"C:\Users\Previous");
}

private void CopyContentsToSubFolderWithSameName(string path)
{
    DirectoryInfo currDir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    DirectoryInfo subDir =
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(currDir.FullName, currDir.Name));
    IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> parentFolders = 
        subDir.Parent.EnumerateDirectories();

    // Copy files in the current directory to the destination directory
    foreach (FileInfo file in currDir.GetFiles())
    {
        file.MoveTo(Path.Combine(subDir.FullName, file.Name));
    }

    // Copy directories (including files) in the current directory 
    // to the destination directory
    foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in parentFolders)
    {
        if (dir.Name != subDir.Name)
        {
            dir.MoveTo(Path.Combine(subDir.FullName, dir.Name));
        }
    }
}
```